# How double quotes are added in LC_COLLATE?

Tags: linux, locale, centos6

On Centos 6.5, running `locale` produces:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_NAME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

After running `export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"`, running `locale` produces:

`LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_NAME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ALL=`

`LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` becomes `LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8`. Double quotes are lost. How LC_COLLATE is set to `"en_US.UTF-8"`? If I run `export LC_COLLATE='"en_US.UTF-8"'`, there is the following error:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_COLLATE: cannot change locale ("en_US.UTF-8"): No such file or directory
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_COLLATE: cannot change locale ("en_US.UTF-8")
```

How I can set LC_COLLATE to `"en_US.UTF-8"` using some commands?

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? As you can see, `bash` isn't happy about it if you do, and neither will be any other program that references `LC_COLLATE`... The locale code does not expect to get a quoted value from any of the `LC_*` variables. But, if you really must, either your `LC_COLLATE='"en_US.UTF-8"'` or `LC_COLLATE=\"en_US.UTF-8\"` would do the job. Just expect lots of brokenness afterwards.

Comment: @twalberg. `export LC_COLLATE='"en_US.UTF-8"'` gives a error message  as  I have said in my question. After I login  Centos 6.5, I can get `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"`. I want to know how it is achieved by system startup scripts?

Comment: I would guess that that's just odd formatting from the `locale` utility. Check your actual environment variables - I'm almost certain there are no quotes in the `LC_*` variables that are set, and might venture a guess that `locale` is formatting it's output with quotes for the environment variables that aren't set (i.e. they're derived from `LC_ALL`) or something like that...